# Need to combine linux commands in TCL script

Tags: shell, tcl, exec, expect

I want to run this linux command from a TCL script:

```
uname -a | awk '{print $2}'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Pls. show your attempt on it. What have your tried exactly?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/tclsh
exec /usr/bin/uname -a

Comment: I have tried to execute any exec command in TCL script, but none of them is not working "exec /bin/sort -u /tmp/data.in | /bin/wc -l"

Comment: The `exec` command does what you want. You need to show us the exact script you have tried and the response that you say is "not working." Otherwise, we are just guessing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290981/need-to-execute-linux-commands-in-tcl-scripts    --> Please look into this link I have explained the case clearly Thanks in Advance

Comment: The link shows the linux programs you wish to execute and the Tcl `exec` command executes programs. However, we still need to see your attempt at a Tcl script and the response it gives.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/tclsh
#puts "Hello World"
exec /usr/bin/uname -n "I have tried to just exec to execute linux command but here itself I am getting an error

Answer (score 5):

In Tcl, you launch subprocesses and simple pipelines using the `exec` command. (More complex pipelines are usually made via `open` or through the Expect extension.) There are two ways to make your code work with that.

### 1. Convert the quotes

The bourne shell single quote is very *very* similar to braces in Tcl. (Except Tcl can nest braces easily.) This means that you can write:

```
exec uname -a | awk {{print $2}}
```

### 2. Delegate to the shell

Sometimes, it is difficult to do that conversion. Fortunately, you can just ask the shell to do it for you:

```
set theScriptlet {uname -a | awk '{print $2}'}
exec bash -c $theScriptlet
```

## 3. Stop using awk to get the hostname!

Most of the time though, you probably shouldn't be using awk as a subprocess from Tcl if you can help it; awk is, after all, a programming language of its own.

```
set unameinfo [exec uname -a]
set host [lindex [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $unameinfo] 1]
```

Though you can get the information more directly too:

```
set host [exec uname -n]
```

```
set host [exec hostname]
```

```
set host [info hostname]
```

Be aware that the last option can take surprisingly long in some configurations of Mac OS X (due to weirdnesses in the networking stack that are *probably* to do with IPv6 resolution). It also doesn't always produce *quite* the same information; it depends on exactly what you're actually going to do with the information…

Comment: Thanks for the the reply, but unfortunately none of the command is working properly #!/usr/bin/tclsh
set theScriptlet {uname -a | awk '{print $2}'}
exec bash -c $theScriptlet


set unameinfo [exec uname -a]
set host [lindex [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $unameinfo] 1]


set host [exec hostname]
======Please look into the command and let me know If I want to make any changes